# Why can't get correct RGB img of Landsat 8 using np.dstack

Tags: gdal, remote-sensing, numpy

I use np.dstack to stack Band4, Band3, and Band2 of Landsat8 data to get ture color image,I use code from Milos Miljkovic, but the result looks incorrect.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob
import gdalnumeric
def read_band(n):
if n in range(1,12):
    tif_list = glob.glob('*.TIF')
    band_name = 'B' + str(n) + '.TIF'
    img_id = [id for id, band_string in enumerate(tif_list) if band_name in band_string ]
    img = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(tif_list[img_id[0]])
    return img

b2 = read_band(2)
b3 = read_band(3)
b4 = read_band(4)
img_rgb = np.dstack((b4,b3,b2))
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons for the error:

1. I have a feeling that your script may not be selecting the correct bands. You should sort the input bands using sorted(glob.glob("*.TIF")) before converting them into numpy arrays.
2. You should rescale your bands / numpy arrays to uint8 format before plotting.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import gdalnumeric
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

BandList = glob.glob('*.TIF')
# returns: ['B4.TIF', 'B6.TIF', 'B3.TIF', 'B5.TIF', 'B1.TIF', 'B7.TIF', 'B2.TIF']

BandList = sorted(BandList)
# returns: ['B1.TIF', 'B2.TIF', 'B3.TIF', 'B4.TIF', 'B5.TIF', 'B6.TIF', 'B7.TIF']

RGB_Image = np.dstack((gdalnumeric.LoadFile(BandList[3]), gdalnumeric.LoadFile(BandList[2]), gdalnumeric.LoadFile(BandList[1]))).astype('uint8')

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
plt.imshow(RGB_Image, interpolation='nearest')
plt.savefig('TestImage.png', format='png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

And here is the output image:
[image]